# Editing the latest revision of certain types of posts (incl. tag wikis) within the grace period throws an error (but succeeds anyway)

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a site where you have tag wiki editing privileges (20k+ graduated, 4k+ beta) and edit the tag wiki (not the excerpt).
2. Make some changes.
3. Click "Save Edits".
4. Go to the revision history of that same tag wiki.
5. Edit the latest revision. (the edit link should have a GUID in it)
6. Make some changes.
7. Click "Save Edits" again, making sure that you're within the five-minute grace period of the *previous* time you saved your edits.

Outcome:

- You get this generic error message:
  [image: "An error occurred submitting the edit."]
- The edit saves successfully, despite the error message.

I can also reproduce this error with diamond-only WikiPlaceholders (like the list of off-topic things at /tour), but not with questions or answers.