# When submitting a tag wiki edit from the revision history during the grace period, I get redirected to the site home page rather than to the wiki page

Tags: bug, edits, tag-wiki, grace-period, trusted-user

When I make a binding edit to a tag wiki or tag wiki excerpt from the revision history as a 20k+ user during the grace period (editing the individual portion rather than both at the same time), and proceed to save my edit, I get redirected back to the site home page rather than to the wiki I was editing.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a tag wiki description page of a tag that has a wiki (such as [design](/questions/tagged/design)). (This can be accessed by clicking "Learn more" from the general tag link).
2. Click "History", then click the "Edit" button on the latest revision.
3. Type up and save an edit. This will direct you back to the tag wiki page.
4. Repeat step 2.
5. Make another edit within 5 minutes of saving the prior edit.

The expected behavior is that one should be redirected back to the tag wiki page they were editing, which was at `/tags/[tag name]/info`, as with the initial edit. However, instead, I'm directed back to the site home page. This is inconsistent with the behavior for questions and answers, on which I'm redirected back to the post I was editing on grace period edits. The above expected behavior is what correctly happens when I make a tag wiki edit using the "Edit tag info" form that edits both the wiki and the excerpt (which also [incorrectly generates a new revision every time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381460/unable-to-submit-grace-period-edits-to-tag-wikis-using-the-edit-tag-info-butto?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Can this please be fixed?

**Update:** This only seems to happen when performing the instructions in this post's first revision shortly after making another edit, to make a *grace period* edit. When making an edit that generates a new revision, I get directed back to the wiki page as expected. I thought it happened all the time, but was initially unable to reproduce on a (substantive) tag wiki edit I made today, then I remembered that my prior reproduction attempts were all grace period edits (which were to try and reproduce [this other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381460/unable-to-submit-grace-period-edits-to-tag-wikis-using-the-edit-tag-info-butto?noredirect=1&lq=1)). As such, I've updated the instructions.

Comment: This is hard to test because you need to find a tag wiki that does indeed need editing otherwise you risk submitting a test edit. Can someone can confirm in the comments this is happening?

Comment: @bad_coder You could change it back within the grace period, provided you use the same method of making the edit through the post history link due to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381460/unable-to-submit-grace-period-edits-to-tag-wikis-using-the-edit-tag-info-butto). Unlike test edits to posts, tag wiki edits don't bump to the home page.

Comment: I didn't know you could roll-back tag wiki edits without leaving a trace, but I don't want to risk trying it. I'll reiterate my previous previous comment asking a second user to independently confirm the bug.

Comment: @bad_coder Not exactly a rollback, and not exactly without a trace: you manually undo the changes you made (or copy and paste the text of the previous revision) and your edit will appear blank and the summary will show as "[Edit removed during grace period]". The actual test edit won't be in the history.

Comment: No repro on the one site I have full tag wiki edit privileges (Literature)

Comment: @bobble After some further attempts, I discovered this only happens for *grace period* edits (which I didn't catch before as my previous attempts were also attempts to reproduce [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381460/unable-to-submit-grace-period-edits-to-tag-wikis-using-the-edit-tag-info-butto?noredirect=1&lq=1)). When making an edit that generates a new revision, it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix has been released to address this bug. Now tag wiki quick edits (a.k.a "grace period edits") will properly redirect the user back to the tag wiki in question.

###### What happened?

There was a discrepancy between the tag wiki edit page (`/edit-tag-wiki/{tagId}`), and our more generic post edit page (`/post/{postId}/edit`) that would result in users being redirected to different pages depending on if the edit in question was done during the edit grace period.

The logic to determine where to redirect the user made an incorrect assumption about what type of content was being edited, and instead had to rely on a known safe landing page, which in this case was the homepage of the current site.